# Visual Studio doesn't see Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Few days ago i had to reinstall VS. So after uninstallation, I downloaded VS2010 Ultimate from MSDNAA and installed it. Everything went without any trouble, but when i run VS I found, that there wasn't a Team Explorer.

So i downloaded TE from [Team Explorer link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=329). But after installation TE, Visual Studio still doesn't see TE. There is nothing in Menu -> View and Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Source Control.

What should I do now?

Comment: Are you sure about the version? Ultimate should have Team Explorer by default.

Answer (score 6):

Are you able to see Team Explorer which is tabbed along with the solution explorer (At the bottom of the solution explorer window)? If not click view->Team Explorer (Ctrl+M). From there you should be able to connect to your TFS instance.

Comment: I've written above, that I haven't Team Exporer in Menu -> View.

Comment: Believe VS2010 comes with TE along with the installation. The TE you installed is a stand alone shell version of the IDE used to connect to TFS source control (For the ones who doesn't want VS2010 Development IDE). But regardless of that, I couldn't be of much help here. Also if you go to Help, are you able to see MS VS 2010 Team Explorer included in the installed products?

Answer (score 3):

When you install the Visual Studio, then Team Explorer comes by default with VS.
You can check Team Explorer in View->TeamExplorer [image]

If you do not found Team Viewer in your View then you can download it from below link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/05/reintroducing-the-team-explorer-standalone-installer/

or you can download it from vs installer.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

I was missing some menus from the Team Explorer side panel.
what fixed it was resetting user settings by manually running `devenv.com /resetuserdata` from the visual studio folder.

To me it was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com /resetuserdata
```

Notice: this will reset your settings, so make sure you import / export it first (if you require anything specific) .

[image: Image of TFS side panel]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using TFS. Have you connected to a TFS instance using the menu Team -> Connect to team foundation server?

Comment: I don't have any menu Team :(

Comment: Radoslaw does not have a team menu (removed this as answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329